# Woher kommt der Östereichische Begriff "Erlagschein"?

Tags: etymology, austrian

Ich habe gerade auf [Wien Heute.at](http://www.heute.at/news/oesterreich/wien/art23652,647916) einen Bericht über einen falschen [Schwarzkappler](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzkappler)
gefunden, der Schwarzfahrern die nicht bar bezahlten einen [Erlagschein](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlagschein#cite_note-0) gegeben hatte.

Beide Begriffe werden in Wikipedia erklärt. Doch während die Herkunft von "Schwarzkappler" nachvollziehbar ist, fehlt für "Erlagschein" eine Erklärung.

Answer (score 7):

Ein Erlag meint in Österreich einfach die Zahlung eines Geldbetrags und kommt seinerseits von ["erlegen"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erlegen).

Answer (score 3):

"Erlegen" hat auch die Bedeutung "bezahlen", dies ist zwar in den meisten deutschen Gebieten aus der Umgangssprache verschwunden (auch in Östereich) - im Bankwesen (ursprünglich auch im Postwesen) war der Begriff Erlagschein allerdings offenbar schon so tief verwurzelt, dass der Begriff Erlagschein erhalten blieb.

Comment: Man konnte früher seine [Schuld erlegen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GE08007)

Comment: das klingt sehr realistisch!